# addpackageasync attempted to reference a token that does not exist (Error Code 0x800703F0)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently trying to build a company hub for WindowsPhone 8.1. So I made the AET and registered as a Company in the Dev Center. 
Now I have a problem by calling the InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync() method. It gives me the Error in the title:

addpackageasync an attemp was made to reference a token that does not exist (Error Code 0x800703F0)

but I can install apps via InternetExplorer or E-Mail.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Comment: Same issue here ! But don't know how to fix ! If anyone can help ...

Comment: Ok got that running. After juggling arround with the developer ids in the manifest I think I solved it finnaly by unregister my phone as a developer phone. As long as it is unregistered now I can use the API for installation. But I have still some issues in lunching the right application. Hope that helps...

Comment: NOt quite sure which error I got, but found this page: http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/07/31/Windows-Phone-81-APPX-Code-Signing-Weird-Error-When-Installing.aspx

Comment: Same issue for me, how can I unregister my phone as a developper phone?

Comment: Oke before you unregister your phone, be sure that ALL publisher ids match the id of your signing certificate. For Phone unregister, go to the start menu and search vor the visualstudio folder, there you have the tool with which you registered your phone as a developer phone. Launch that again and you can unregister your phone.